# Left clicks sometimes do not register

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, click

I have noticed on several Macs like Mac Mini's and a MacBook Pro running OSX versions all the way up to El Capitan that left mouse or trackpad first time clicks sometimes don't register when clicking on the "x" to close the window or also on tabs.

I noticed that clicking anywhere inside the active window first will wake up the "x" or tabs.

This looks like it may be a bug that was never reported.

Does anyone else have this issue and is there a setting I can set?

Thanks.

*** Update ***

I'm now using El Capitan for quite a while and Apple has not fixed this issue yet.

Comment: what do you mean by "I noticed that clicking anywhere inside the active window first will wake up the "x" or tabs." ?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71878/first-click-doesnt-register?rq=1 - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/trackpad-and-mouse-require-two-taps-clicks-to-register-first-click?lq=1 & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/after-a-while-the-trackpad-or-mouse-requires-me-to-click-twice-to-be-able-to-re?rq=1

Comment: Hi Enzo. As an example I will open an email message then will want to close the window. When I move the cursor over the red dot to close the window, the cursor shows the hand cursor and not an arrow cursor. When the cursor is a hand I can't click the red x to close the window. If I move the cursor over to the body part of the message then click the body part then move the cursor over to the red x, it will change to an arrow cursor so clicking on the red x will close the window. The same thing happens if a window also has tabs such as using the Chrome browser.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin. I checked your links and it's not any of those. We have 2 mac mini computers and a mac book pro and the same thing happens on all of our computers. I can click multiple times on the red x button and it will not register the click unless I first move the cursor to another location in the window and then click in that other location first.

Comment: Now we've reached 10.11.4 it would be interesting to see if people still have this issue, or if it's quietly faded into history. None of the "me too" answers below give sufficient information to make an educated guess.

Comment: I have this exact problem and it's really annoying. I am running 15' Mac Book Pro from Year 2015, running OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

Comment: Okay, I had Karabinar installed to change my mouse scroll behavior. I have it uninstalled and the problem seems went away.

Comment: Update: Uninstalling Karabinar didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I've finally found the solution for my case, I had to go to System Preferences, clicked on mouse, then changed Double-Click speed on fast.

Comment: I just purchased another Macbook Pro and it already had El Capitan installed and very soon after setting up the computer, it updated before I could test the issue and this computer does not have that issue. Looks like they fixed it for this computer. It's the 2015 year version.

Comment: This happens on 2 MacBook Pros I own. One is on Sierra, the other High Sierra. Sometimes a left click does not register at all. This began very recently just before HS was released.