# Trackpad often does not register first left click

Tags: mouse, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I have an issue in which I often have to left click twice in order for a single left click to register. This issue is described very nicely in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/trackpad-and-mouse-require-two-taps-clicks-to-register-first-click). In summary, the first trackpad left click often does not register, which requires that I left click again. It frequently, but not always, follows a short period of trackpad inactivity.

It appears that [several](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/after-a-while-the-trackpad-or-mouse-requires-me-to-click-twice-to-be-able-to-re?noredirect=1&lq=1) [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71878/first-click-doesnt-register?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212791/left-clicks-sometimes-do-not-register?noredirect=1&lq=1) have been asked about this very issue. These questions have been asked over a span of more than eight years (as of mid 2020), concern multiple hardware platforms both older and newer than my mid 2012 Air, and have garnered many thousands of views. So I guess this is not an isolated problem.

Unfortunately, three of the four questions were resolved by addressing troublesome software that I don't use (jTouch, Mumble, Spotify) and the fourth has no posted resolution. I don't currently have any software installed that is intended to modify my trackpad input. I can only think of one application (OpenEMU) that could be relevant since it has Input Monitoring permission, but I rarely use it, it isn't currently running, and I think that's just for the keyboard anyway. Here are a few of my machine's specifications:

- Macbook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- Intel i7-3667U
- 8 GB RAM 1600 MHz DDR3
- macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287) [Upgraded last week!]

Does anyone have any idea how I might go about troubleshooting this issue? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to include your hardware specs?

Comment: @fsb I've added some basic information. Is there anything in particular that you suspect may be relevant?

Comment: As you've mentioned, this issue has been happening for years with different Macs.  It's unlikely a solution can be presented here to fix your problem if the other answers didn't help.  Can you try running the [AHT](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/diagnose-problems-mh35727/mac)?

Comment: I’ve experienced this before and every time it was a failing (or already failed) track pad. You need to replace it.

Comment: @fsb Unfortunately, AHT fails to run on my machine (see [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/568059/MacBook+Pro+2013+-+cannot+load+Apple+Hardware+Test) or [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250285425)) so I suppose I'll have to bring it to an Apple store. Is there anything else I can do for now? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Allan I hope you're wrong - the sudden onset of the problem had me pretty convinced it was more likely software - but I am now noticing that the issue may be be pressure-dependent. If I apply just enough pressure for the tactile click and no more, it will not register the click. I don't recall if the trackpad always responded this way. Perhaps I occasionally click with very little pressure? As a test / stopgap, do you know a way I can modify a software pressure threshold? Should I attempt to tighten the screws that hold the trackpad in place to increase relative pressure? Thanks for the help.